# How to use bitwise to convert a 4-bit binary number to an 8-bit binary number?

Tags: bit-shift

My goal is to write a bitwise expression to represent an 8-bit number in the right column by a 4-bit number in the left column.
Hope someone will help me to solve this question.
Thanks very much!

**4 bits**                      **8 bits** 

0001                      00000011 

0010                      00001100 

0011                      00001111 

0100                      00110000 

0101                      00110011 

0110                      00111100 

0111                      00111111 

1000                      11000000 

1001                      11000011 

1010                      11001100 

1011                      11001111 

1100                      11110000 

1101                      11110011 

1110                      11111100 

1111                      11111111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way is from a 4-bit word `dcba` to first generate `0d0c0b0a` by shifting each bit in the right place:

```
t = (x & 0b0001) | ((x & 0b0010) << 1) | ((x & 0b0100) << 2) | ((x & 0b1000) << 3)
```

and then duplicate the bits:

```
return t | (t << 1)
```

A trickier alternative that needs fewer instructions is to first introduce a gap that leaves `a` and `c` in the right place:

```
t = (x | (x << 2)) & 0b00110011
```

and then shift `b` and `d` and introduce the duplication:

```
return ((t + (t | 0b1010101)) ^ 0b1010101) & 0b11111111
```

(the final `&` is not needed if the data type is limited to 8 bits anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a type and implement what's necessary for `MutableCollection`, and `RandomAccessCollection`, then you can use [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence)'s [`reduce`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce).

```swift
0b1001.afterMitosis // 0b11_00_00_11
```

```swift
extension FixedWidthInteger where Self: _ExpressibleByBuiltinIntegerLiteral {
  var afterMitosis: Self {
    bits.enumerated().prefix(4).reduce(0) {
      let clonedBitPair = $1.element | $1.element << 1
      return $0 | clonedBitPair << ($1.offset * 2)
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension FixedWidthInteger where Self: _ExpressibleByBuiltinIntegerLiteral {
  var bits: Bits<Self> {
    get { .init(integer: self) }
    set { self = newValue.integer }
  }
}

/// The bits of an integer, from least significant to most.
public struct Bits<Integer: FixedWidthInteger & _ExpressibleByBuiltinIntegerLiteral> {
  public var integer: Integer
}

// MARK: - MutableCollection, RandomAccessCollection
extension Bits: MutableCollection, RandomAccessCollection {
  public typealias Index = Int

  public var startIndex: Index { 0 }
  public var endIndex: Index { Integer.bitWidth }

  public subscript(index: Index) -> Integer {
    get { integer >> index & 1 }
    set {
      integer &= ~(1 << index)
      integer |= (newValue & 1) << index
    }
  }
}
```